Change system sounds for specific actions like plugging in a USB in MacOS
Im looking for a way to change different system sounds in macos sonoma. In windows and in older versions of macos it is possible to change all kinds of system sounds to whatever audio file you want. I talk about specific sound actions like plugging into USB or removing it, Startup sounds or the like. Is there any way to do that in newer versions? Since there is no setting for it, I was hoping for a more hacky way.
I saw that you can add more sounds to the list, but im looking for specifically changing sounds like usb action, startup, alerts etc..
Help appreaciated
